# How to send an external request to a web service

Tags: php, symfony

I need to send a request to a external web Service, My web service return a json. The 2 projects are local. The first is localhost/symfony... and the second localhost/login/index.php

```
  $uri = "http://localhost/login/index.php";
  $request =  Request::create($uri, 'GET', array('test' => 'test'));
```

I do not know how to send the request and retrieve the response.

Comment: Are they both Symfony projects? Are they separated bundles or you use them as connected bundles?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand - you need your PHP code to make a request to two different services, wait for responses from them, then parse the responses before rendering HTML for the browser? Or do you need your browser to make AJAX requests to these two services after loading the page?

Comment: This seems very bad designed - please provide more information regarding what your app/services do.

Comment: For example: when sending a form, my Symfony application retrieves the data and send to an external web server. The external web server retrieves the data and return a response.

Comment: @user2956298 are they both Symfony projects? You need to this by CURL commnad

Comment: @Javad No, the web service is not into symfony, php 5.3.
You think i need to use CURL for the 2 projects ?

Comment: So that makes it much easier; yes you can just send the request to your webservice from your controller in Symfony by using CURL (if the webservice has authentication service you need to first get the valid session ID again by using CURL then use that session ID for your CURL request). If you clarify a none session base I will provide an example as answer for you

Answer (score 2):

Request object are for internal use. You better use HTTP clients like

- [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)
- [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)
- [raw curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to get the data in json format from your web service, and later you can parse it using [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).